# JavaFX 3D for >1 million Box-objects

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I have been working in JavaFX to create a 3D model. I've followed [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm) and everything is working peachy except for when I start adding my own data. As a minimal working example, consider the example application from said guide (*note: you might have to add the following class variable which was missing from the guide:* `double modifierFactor = 0.1;`) and replace the `buildMolecule()` function body with:

```
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int dim = 10;
int dimhalf = dim>>1;
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < dim; k++) {
            Box b = new Box(10, 10, 10);
            b.setTranslateX((i-dimhalf)*10);
            b.setTranslateY((j-dimhalf)*10);
            b.setTranslateZ((k-dimhalf)*10);
            b.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
            root.getChildren().add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Run the application (I use additional flags `-Xmx6g -Xms6g`) and play around with the value of dim to see the effect. Should you encounter flickering (I did, due to `depthBuffering = true` on the `Scene` instance), try setting `CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP = 100`. You may also want to set `CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE` to something like `-1500` for larger values of dim.

This works fine (on my machine) for dim < 20. For dim = 30, the initial render is still fast but the standard operations (rotate with LMB, zoom with RMB and translate with MMB) are choppy. This grows worse and worse for increasing dim until 70 at which point the initial rendering takes multiple seconds, but interacting with the scene is basically impossible.

I'm facing a situation where I need to render anywhere between 1 million and 10 million `Box` instances (so dim >= 100). Is this possible? Are there tricks I can use to speed up performance?

For those interested, the underlying model is an octree.

Comment: Are there tricks I can use to speed up performance? Yes. Remove all `Box` es that are covered by other `Box`es anyways. This should allow you to render the scene with dim=50 with the performance of a scene with dim=20 (3 * 50² < 20³)

Comment: @fabian thanks, but for my application unfortunately the shape is not perfectly cuboid, computing only the visible mini cuboids is not an easy task. However, it might still help... on the other hand, I still won't be able to reach dim 100 :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that you're adding a million independent 3D scenegraph nodes which all have to be managed, event detected, rendered/occluded, etc.  Just not going to happen, regardless of your rendering system.
For super dense 3D scenegraphs like this you need to convert the data to a single contiguous triangle mesh whose triangles have been wound in a way that the camera only shows datapoints.  Definitely not for the faint of heart, which is why we created a [ScatterMesh class](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/ScatterMesh.java) in the http://www.fxyz3d.org/ repo to make it easier.

There is no sample for this class yet, but here's how I use it as demonstrated at [2:05 of this video](https://youtu.be/Z2zRRe0UzgI?t=124):

> DirectedScatterMesh periapsisMap3D = new DirectedScatterMesh(data, true, point3dSize, 0);
>       periapsisMap3D.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL); //makes mini triangles solid
>       periapsisMap3D.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530,colorByAngleOut); //colorByAngleOut is a Function that maps x,y numbers to a color.

setTextureModeVertices3D allows you to specify a color map which is then converted to a Texture and then PhongMaterial and wrapped precisely around the 3D structure so that the colors you specify in the Function are mapped to the correct faces.

Below is my colorByAngleOut Function so you at least have an idea how it works:

> Function colorByAngleOut = p->
>   Math.abs(Math.atan2(p.y, Math.sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.z*p.z))); //in javafx
>   3D y -> z and vice versa

Where p is a point3D and I'm essentially calculating the angle of the spacecraft out from the ecliptic plane.

To add this entire 3D structure, which is a glorified TriangleMesh when it comes down to it, is as simple as adding it to the 3D scene like any other object:

> sceneRoot.getChildren().add(periapsisMap3D);

Please note that the video actually shows a modified version of the ScatterMesh which allows directed tetrahedrons, allowing additional data dimenstions to be rendered. This is not supported by the current FXyz build, it is a customization I made which is not open source.

Comment: I did a similar thing in HTML+JavaScript once, where I had to draw about 100k objects on a 2D canvas. There I was able to get away with 1 full render cycle on an off-screen canvas and then exporting the result to an image (all in memory) for which the mouse operations then basically moved a viewport over the image. Is there any chance there is a way to derive a scattermesh from a scene graph full of 3D objects? I'm afraid the physical shape of the thing I'm rendering is so irregular (and different each time at runtime) that making a mesh will be really difficult.